# Asset not loading, css, js or even images are not loading or linking in my Laravel 7 project

Tags: laravel

I don't know how else to go about this issue. I've tried several suggestions I've seen online but to no avail. I'm working with laravel 7

My view is not loading any file from my public folder. Even images uploaded from the view to the directory is not loading back to view when called. I've symlink the storage and the public directory. However, I observed that my storage folder created was a shortcut but I expect that should be correct.

These are different ways I can remember I tried to call an image from the directory for example

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/cover_images/img1.jpg') }}" alt="">

 <img src="{{ URL::asset('storage/cover_images/img1.jpg') }}" alt="">

<img src="{{ Storage::url('cover_images/img1.jpg') }}" alt="">

<img src="/public/cover_images/img1.jpg">
```

Also note that all CDNs or images referenced externally are working properly.

Comment: In which directory of your project is exactly the image you want to show?

Comment: In the public directory, thank you for your response

Comment: If it is in the root of the `/public` directory, accesses the file directly `<img src="/img1.jpg" />`.

Comment: Or with asset helper `<img src="{{ asset('/img1.jpg') }}" />`

Comment: I've tried all that before wasn't working just tried again now same result. Rehmat said something about ASSET_URL in the .env file, i realize i don't even have it in the file. I wouldn't know if you have the right configuration for that the path. Cheers

Comment: Thank you so much buddy, so the problem has to be with ASSET_URL in the .env file. It wasn't set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you symlink the storage public disc, a shortcut directory `storage` is created in your Laravel project's public folder. Now the `asset()` helper of Laravel isn't restricted to access storage files only, instead you can use this to access any file on the public path. By default, `asset()` helper uses the public directory as the root.

For example, if you have uploaded an image to `public/images/first.png`, then you can use `asset('images/first.png')` to generate the full URL for the image.

If you have properly symlinked the storage disk then you should be seeing files in the newly created `public/storage` directory. If it doesn't contain any files, you must have symlinked it improperly.

To ensure that `asset()` helper works fine, create a directory `foo` in your Laravel project's `public` folder and place some dummy file, i.e. `test.png` in that `foo` directory. Now using `asset('foo/test.png')`, you should be getting the full and valid URL to `test.png` file.

If it doesn't, maybe you have configured the asset helper's URL to some other destination using `ASSET_URL` in .env file.

Comment: Thank you so much Rehmat, the symlink is working properly I suppose because all images uploaded from the view are all in the specified directory in the public but I get something informative from you now. That is the ASSET_URL, I just checked my .env file now and couldn't find anything named ASSET_URL in there. So I suppose something must have went wrong during installations or something. Please what should I define that to be. Thank you once again

Comment: Thank you so much Rehmat, just solved the problem. So the problem was that the ASSET_URL in the .env file is not set. Appreciate

Comment: @Willydbd Glad to know that you figured this out. Consider marking this answer as the accepted one if this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not include `storage` or `public` , if you have symlink. You can call directly your asset like:

```
  <img src="{{ asset('cover_images/img1.jpg') }}" alt="">
```

Comment: then inspect the image element and see what is link of your image in the browser. ( and comment here ) @Willydbd